# App crashes when onClick method is called

Tags: android, permissions

I want to read a text message from a phone but the app crashes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tx ;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tx = findViewById(R.id.text);


    }
    public void grant(View view) {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission is granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    public void show(View view)
    {


        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        final Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                null, null, null, null);
        String sms = "";
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            sms += "From :" + cur.getString(1) + " : " + cur.getString(3)+"\n";
        }
        tx.setText(sms);
        setContentView(view);
    }
```

Error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7339) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14221) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7305) 
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27787) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7058) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5259)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5090)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5003)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:460)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:145)
        at com.example.final_project.MainActivity.show(MainActivity.java:76)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are not a debugging service. Please read [ask] and [mcve], then [edit] the question accordingly. Dumping only your code and error is not very polite to us volunteers, so please include an explanation what the code does, where the error occurs, and what you have tried yourself to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the second `setContentView()`:

```
    tx.setText(sms);
    setContentView(view);  // <<- here
}
```

`setContentView()` should only ever be called to set the layout of the activity, which you've already set in `onCreate()`. As such, the `View` object being passed into `show(View)` already has a parent as it's already been inflated, and thus cannot be reused without being detached from its original parent. I'm presuming this `View` is the button you've clicked if this method is acting as an `OnClickListener` interface